# Add Label into select box (<select>)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to to add label inside select box using bootstrap as shown:

*Before select an option*

[image: before select an option]

and after we select an option label should appear in small size

*After select an option*

[image: After select an option]:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="sector">Sector</label>
    <div class="label form-label-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="sector">
            <option>Civilian</option>
            <option>Officer</option>
            <option>Retirement</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What your attempt? Post your code here!

Comment: I added it to the post

Comment: You may want to look into the documentation of Material Design. https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/select. IMO, your question is a bit broad and you're looking for someone else to do your job.

Comment: This will come down to a mix between CSS and JavaScript. I don't think Bootstrap is necessary for this.

Answer (score 1):

See the live example below:

```js
$('#sector option[value=temp]').hide();
$('#sector').change(function() {
  $('#sector option[value=temp]').show();
 $("#sector option[value=temp]").css("font-size", "small");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="sector">Sector</label>
  <div class="label form-label-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="sector">
      <option disabled value="temp">Sector</option>
      <option value="Civilian">Civilian</option>
      <option value="Officer">Officer</option>
      <option value="Retirement">Retirement</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```